# Rails - Specific Time Zones in Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a drop down in my form that displays all the time zones like this:

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, /United Kingdom/, :default => "London" %>
```

but I now only want to display about 10 different ones from around the world. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
```

will give you all the timezones

You can manually select 10 from them by doing

```
f.collection_select :time_zone, [ ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Alaska'], ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Hawaii'] ], :name, :to_s
```

Or if you want random 10 from the array

```
  f.time_zone_select :time_zone,  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sample(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using your first example - this selects the two you have included but then the whole list is included after. I don't want the rest, only the ones I choose - any ideas.

Comment: With your changes it now works - do you mind explaning your alteration?